# pygame.init() terminates program with no error

Tags: python, pygame

Summary: When I run code pygame.init(), it terminates program, with no error.

I tried calling print() before and after init(), and print statement after init() (and any other code beyond this line) is ignored and terminated.

I thought my python version was a problem, so I tried both 3.6.0 and 3.7.4, and both had same issue. I also have tried wrapping whole code in try/catch, and nothing was caught.

One thing that was really weird was that, when I run these code in command line (by typing py), after running init(), console exited from python.

```
C:>py
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygame
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
>>> pygame.get_init()
False
>>> pygame.init()
C:>
```

- I installed pygame by running: pip install pygame

Even very short code such as this below does not work for me,:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.quit()
```

but I put some test code to see what is happening. Here is very simple test that I did:

```
import pygame

def testFunct():
    print('successfully quit')
pygame.register_quit(testFunct) #this should print when pygame quits

print(pygame.get_init())        #False
pygame.init()                   #program stops here for few seconds, then terminates
print('initialization done')    #this line is ignored
pygame.quit()                   #quit message is not printed
```

Here is the result:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
False
```

I'm sorry to ask, because I know this is definately unreproducable, since this isn't the code's problem. Am I missing anything for installation?

Comment: did you run in console/terminal/cmd.exe to check if it gives error message ?

Comment: PyGame uses C/C++ library [SDL 1.2](https://www.libsdl.org/) . Maybe you have to install it manually.

Comment: Did you catch all exceptions (*e.g.*, `SystemExit`, not just `Exception`)?  Can you attach a debugger?

Comment: @furas your solution fixed it! I did run in cmd and it did not gave any error message. After downloading .dll from SDL website, it runs fine.